# удаление свойства объекта

Tags: reactjs

не получается изменить или удалить свойство объекта, при удалении ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot delete property '_Posts' of #, при изменении Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_Posts' of object '#

```
setPosts (CurrentPosts) {
        this._Posts = CurrentPosts
    }
```

выше создание метода, который подменяет свойство объекта другим свойством, ниже его вызов

```
let CurrentPosts = props.getPosts()

let Posts = CurrentPosts.map(el =>
    <Post text={el.text} likes={el.likes}/>
)
let a = React.createRef()

let onChange = () => {
    CurrentPosts.isFrozen ? console.log('da') : console.log('no')
    let newLetter = a.current.value
    newLetter = newLetter.replace(`${CurrentPosts[3].text}`, ``)
    CurrentPosts[3].text += newLetter
    console.log(CurrentPosts[3].text)
    props.setPosts(CurrentPosts)
    props.render()
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: укажите что такое `#` и приведите пример кода где вы делаете действия удаления и изменения

Comment: @DaniilLoban отредактировал пост

Comment: чем является this в данном случае (this._Posts) это компонент или что?

Comment: @DaniilLoban _Posts это массив, который находится внутри объекта, и this указатель на него

Comment: если это обычный объект все должно удалятся без проблем, приводите полный код который будет воспроизводить ошибку, возможно Вы дважды пытаетесь удалить (т.е. удалить то что удалилось - будет ошибка) перед удалением нужно проверять наличие удаляемого